# Can I access crossdomain files outside the originally requested domain?

Tags: apache-flex, flash, security, sandbox, crossdomain.xml

> **Flash Player 10 specifies:**
>
> *"Redirects to policy files outside the originally requested domain will
>   continue to cause policy files to be
>   ignored by Flash Player."*

Is there a way to access policy files outside the domain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't fully understand your question.

A policy file on a given domain (no matter the exact path) can only give access on that domain and subdomains.

Using `Security.loadPolicyFile`, you can load it from an arbitrary URL on that domain, but you cannot grant access to domain B with a policy file from domain A.

---

#### Edit:

If you could give access to B from A, being the owner of A, this whole policy thing would be pointless. You would serve the swf from A and serve a policy file that grants access to B from A, so why have policy files anyway?

Comment: yeah  "you cannot grant access to domain B with a policy file from domain A ..."  ... 

im wondering  .... is tht impossible? ny other way?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about flash, but you can load any javascript you want by dynamically adding script tags to the page, or even including them into your page at load time. Just add append a tag to the end of head with the script URL you need to load. But you should do this only if you trust the script.

Answer (score 0):

You can load policy files from anywhere using:

```
Security.loadPolicyFile(url:String)
```